# Cannot play CS:GO on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, steam, opengl

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my old PC. This are my PC's specs:

**Processor**: Intel® Core™2 CPU 6400 @ 2.13GHz × 2 
**GPU**: Radeon X1600 PRO
**Memory (RAM)**: 2GB
**Disk (space)**: 155GB

So, I decided to play CS:GO. I installed Steam with Ubuntu Software Center and then installed CS:GO from Steam. I tried to run it and I got an error: Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glColorMaskIndexedEXT'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated. I was searching for solution for about 2 week, but nothing helped. I even had to reinstall Ubuntu because of a login loop XD. 
Then I decided to try and use Wine and PlayOnLinux. I installed everything correctly and when I tried to run CS:GO I got and unknown error.
I know that my PC is realy old but when I used to have windows XP installed on it, I could play CS:GO without any problems. Can you guys please tell me what to do in a simple way, step by step? I would be very grateful for your help :)

Here are some more maybe useful informations:

lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV530 [Radeon X1600 PRO]

glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.2

If you need any more informations, I will give them to you, just tell me what to look up or type in the terminal and I will do it :)

Comment: the output of  'glxinfo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the driver
To look for boot messages/errors, check

```
dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
```

To see your OpenGL information, you can run the commands below. Make sure your OpenGL renderer string does not say "software rasterizer" or "llvmpipe" because that would mean you have no 3D hardware acceleration:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
```

Removing the proprietary fglrx driver
If you've previously installed the ATI binary/proprietary driver (a.k.a Catalyst/fglrx), you need to make sure it's fully purged before trying to use the open-source ati/radeon driver.
See this page
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx